# OpenGL tile rendering: most efficient way?

Tags: performance, opengl, graphics, 2d

I am creating a tile-based 2D game as a way of learning basic "modern" OpenGL concepts. I'm using shaders with OpenGL 2.1., and am familiar with the rendering pipeline and how to actually draw geometry on-screen. What I'm wondering is the best way to organize a tilemap to render quickly and efficiently. I have thought of several potential methods:

1.) Store the quad representing a single tile (vertices and texture coordinates) in a VBO and render each tile with a separate `draw*` call, translating it to the correct position onscreen and using `uniform2i` to give the location in the texture atlas for that particular tile;

2.) Keep a VBO containing every tile onscreen (already-computed screen coordinates and texture atlas coordinates), using `BufferSubData` to update the tiles every frame but using a single `draw*` call;

3.) Keep VBOs containing static NxN "chunks" of tiles, drawing however many chunks of tiles are at least partially visible onscreen and translating them each into position.

*I'd like to stay away from the last option if possible unless rendering chunks of 64x64 is not too inefficient. Tiles are loaded into memory in blocks of that size, and even though only about 20x40 tiles are visible onscreen at a time, I would have to render up to four chunks at once. This method would also complicate my code in several other ways.

So, which of these is the most efficient way to render a screen of tiles? Are there any better methods?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could do any one of these and they would probably be fine; what you're proposing to render is very, very simple.

#1 will definitely be worse *in principle* than the other options, because you would be drawing many extremely simple “models” rather than letting the GPU do a whole lot of batch work on one draw call. However, if you have *only* 20×40 = 800 tiles visible on screen at once, then this is a trivial amount of work for any modern CPU and GPU (unless you're doing some crazy fragment shader).

I recommend you go with whichever is simplest to program for you, so that you can continue work on your game. I imagine this would be #1, or possibly #2. **If and when** you find yourself with a performance problem, do whichever of #2 or #3 (64×64 sounds like a fine chunk size) lets you spend the least CPU time on *your program*'s part of drawing (i.e. updating the buffer(s)).

Comment: Ok, after some further research on "batching" I think I'll go with #2. Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 1):

I've been recently learning modern OpenGL myself, through OpenGL ES 2.0 on Android. The OpenGL ES 2.0 Programming Guide recommends an "array of structures", that is,

"Store vertex attributes together in a single buffer. The structure represents all attributes of a vertex and we have an array of these attributes per vertex."

While this may seem like it would initially consume a lot of space, it allows for efficient rendering using VBOs and flexibility in texture mapping each tile. I recently did a tiled hex grid using interleaved arrays containing vertex, normals, color, and texture data for a 20x20 tile hex grid on a Droid 2. So far things are running smoothly.